# R ddply columns into binary

Tags: r, dataframe

I was wondering if there is a way to ddply columns into binary mode by median.

Specifically, if I have a data frame with 5 columns, instead of first computing the medians like so and then doing a lapply of some sort can I do this more elegantly all in one step?

```
medians <- apply(myData, 2, median)
lapply(1:5, function(x){ifelse(myData[,x]<medians[x], 0, 1)})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you could do it for the iris data set:

```
iris[-5] <- lapply(iris[-5], function(x) as.integer(x > median(x)))
```

This way you convert the logical vectors produced by the logical condition (x > median(x)) to integer values (0/1).